# Radio button and Frame overlap tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My first radio button overlaps with my frame for some reason, no matter what row or column I place them in.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Radio")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/rutab/Documents/Icons/Radio.ico")

frame = LabelFrame(root).grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 60)
b = Button(frame, width = 10).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

def click(value):
    global frame
    my_label = Label(frame, text = value).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

v = IntVar()
r_1 = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Python', variable = v, value = 1, command = lambda: click(v.get()))
r_2 = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Java', variable = v, value = 2, command = lambda: click(v.get()))
r_3 = Radiobutton(root, text = 'C++', variable = v, value = 3, command = lambda: click(v.get()))

r_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
r_2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
r_3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: This is the output]

As you can see in the output, the button shows how my frame is overlapping the radio button. How do Place my frame under all the radio buttons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: You aren't actually putting anything inside the `LabelFrame` because `frame` is always `None` in your code.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yea thanks, that was the issue I was facing